# Could not create the folder using PHP

Tags: php

I have one issue. I am trying to create folder using PHP but its giving the following error.

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/oditek.in/universityprod/template/insert.php on line 30
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_URL='/var/www/oditek.in/public_html/universityprod/';
$seladmcode='BSC_2018-21_NPR';
$application_no='BSC_2018-21_NPR2018';
$uploaddir = $DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_URL."".$seladmcode."/".$application_no;
if(!is_dir($uploaddir))
    mkdir($uploaddir,0777,true);
?>
```

After getting this error message I assigned the permission `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/oditek.in/public_html/universityprod/` but still I am unable to create the folder. Here permission is already there but still folder could not be created. I need to create the folder inside the `universityprod`.

Comment: Do not use 777, instead use 755 as it is safer.

Comment: Do you have two different `universityprod` folders? Because `/var/www/oditek.in/universityprod/` vs. `/var/www/oditek.in/public_html/universityprod/`

Comment: @spectatorx : Means you talking to assign `755` permission ?

Comment: Yes, but mainly for security purposes. On your local machine 777 is kinda ok but 755 is considered to be more secure and that's why you should use it.

Comment: @kerbholz; Ahh....yes you are right. I think wrong path is provided. Let me to change it and check.

Comment: @kerbholz  good catch thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad it works

Comment: @kerbholz : But its creating without `777` permission,where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure with www-data or  www  (user) has priviledges in the following folder

> /var/www/oditek.in/public_html/universityprod/

Check on this article 
https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Comment: `chmod 777` allows every user to write to that folder though

Comment: Try create path relative to the script location
$uploaddir = $seladmcode."/".$application_no;

if needed you can go up with ../../path_to_universityprod

Answer (score 0):

Try to set default permission for the directory you want to create using `umask` like,

```
<?php
$old = umask(0);
mkdir($uploaddir,0777,true);
umask($old);
?>
```

It's good idea to set directory permission as 755 instead of 777

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php & http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

Don't forget to read the `Note` in the above referred pages.